# How to execute spark-submit with debugging turned on from IntelliJ IDEA and attach to it?

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, spark-submit

I have a MapR cluster of nodes, I have a virtual box vm with a CentOs and a MapR client installed. I use IntelliJ to develop Spark/Scala code.
I can execute this line on my MapR client in order to debug from IntelliJ (remote debug)

```
spark-submit --driver-java-options -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 --master local[2] --class MyClass myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

So after executing the spark-submit, I need to click on the debug button in IntelliJ to launch everything.
I would like to avoid executing the line above on my Mapr client VM each time I want to debug my application. So I wonder if it is possible to manage all the debug from IntelliJ

Do you have any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I wonder if it is possible to manage all the debug from IntelliJ

I hardly believe so.

You have to start `spark-submit` with proper debugging options and use attach to that process using IntelliJ IDEA's **Debug** feature with **Remote** debug configuration.

I use the following to launch `spark-shell` with the JVM with the debugging options turned on (all on a single line).

```
SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 \
  ./bin/spark-shell
```

BTW Using `--driver-java-options` to set the debugging options for the driver's JVM is a very neat idea. Thanks!